# How realistic are legal analysis panels like these?

Tags: realism, the-good-wife

In *The Good Wife* episode 7.15 titled, Targets, Alicia Florrick is selected for a small panel of legal advisers to partake an a legal analysis of some executive order that pertains to killing enemy combatants of the United States. She is one of two selected civilian lawyers, being the wife of the current sitting Illinois Governor.

**7.15 Transcript:**

> And I'm Oren Cleary, Legal Counsel to the Chairman of the Joint Chiefs
>   of Staff. It's a mouthful, I know. This is a confidential session. All
>   of the items and materials discussed here are subject, under penalty
>   of law, to confidentiality rules.
>
> You may take notes during this session, but those notes must be
>   relinquished before we've finished. And no items or evidence may be
>   taken from this room. Understood? Good.
>
> As I'm sure you're aware, the executive branch has taken flack lately
>   for its legal justification regarding Executive Order 12333. **The
>   president has asked for a broader consensus on action item 56-984B.
>   Our two civilian consultants have been granted TS/SCI clearance to
>   take part.** Please break the seal on your briefing materials now.

My question is, do panels like this with some civilian lawyers actually exist to help advise the President on legal matters, especially to help determine an execution of an enemy combatant or terrorist? How realistic is this?

Comment: Interesting. Certainly, they are *possible* (indeed quite sensible) under the National Security Act of 1947 but by their very nature I suspect it would be difficult (if not impossible) to obtain evidence of their existence (and thus realisim( since they would be classified.

Comment: Maybe it was a bad question to ask! I just thought it was interesting, but you're probably right, there probably isn't a lot if any public evidence...

Comment: I like the question and *an* answer is possible but it would be on the lines of "It's possble but probably unproveable" at least in the context of the question. :)

Comment: [White House Counsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Counsel) is a real position that advises the President on legal matters, and I would expect the person appointed to that position to meet most standard definitions of "civilian" (i.e. non-military) at least some of the time. I assume you want to know if they'd ever bring in outside legal professionals (i.e. not those who are part of regular White House staff) for additional opinions? Are you only interested in opinions on military actions?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. You are correct! To be true to the situation featured in the episode, I am interested in both civilians or really "outsiders" and in relation to military matters, such as identifying and targeting an enemy combatant. In this episode, I believe a member of the Justice Department was running the panel, in which there was another inner circle legal analyst, two civilian layers (a conservative and a liberal), and a military attorney.

Comment: I don't know if this matters much in terms of my Q, but they exclude certain evidence on a terrorist in question by focusing on his crimes, in which at first they weren't sure they call him an enemy combatant, since he was an ISIS "preacher" making him a propagandist, but then it was determined that he supplied "bodies" and thus he became an enemy combatant. But then they open anthr book and discover he was born in the US, so then 3 panel members decide to withdraw previous statements so they can learn more about the background and if this panel should really be this person's due process...

Comment: Have you considered asking this on the Law site? Legal experts are more likely to know the answer than movie experts.

Comment: I have yet to join that community and also didn't know if tv series related Q's were permitted there? Is it ok if I let this sit here for a while and if nothing happens in a few days, have it moved there?